# str_replace() to create self-closing tag DOMElement();

Tags: php, dom, str-replace

I try to create html this way, and try to create self closing tag:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
//document creation  here...

function render()
{
    $t = array(
         '></area',
         '></base',
         '></basefont',
         '></br',
         '></col',
         '></hr',
         '></img',
         '></input',
         '></link',
         '></meta'
    );
    $str  = str_replace($t,"/", $doc->saveHTML(), $count);

    echo $str;
    echo $count;
}
```

It doesn't work yet. it's not replacing and i get `$count` return `0`; am I missed something ? How to properly get empty tag like `<img>` or `<input>` to be like `<input />` not `<input></input>` ??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you specifying your Doctype?

Comment: @MikeBrant no, not yet.

Comment: Specify the document type that you want before you get all worried about changing the output. The class will exhibit different output behavior based on DOCTYPE and whether your use saveHTML or saveXML. Like if you are using XHTML DOCTYPE, you likely will want to use saveXML which should fix self-closing tags issues.

Comment: @MikeBrant i just added `echo <!DOCTYPE html>` before `render()` but still not working :(

Comment: ehm, you´re $doc variable is null, you should get warning about trying to get property of a non-object. You should pass it as an argument for render function

Comment: @Charlie That is not how you do it.  You need to use DOMImplementation class to instantiate your document with specific document type. This page in PHP manual gives good example http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php

Comment: @hynner I do print the document, but the problom is only about that str-replace